# Email Services vs On Demand Email to Case

Tags: apex, case, apex-email-service, email2case

I am extremely new to this functionality (able to create records in Salesforce via emails).

Would appreciate if someone can correct my understanding between these two.

**Email Services :**

These services allow email sent to a salesforce generated email to be processed by Apex classes.
I am assuming that along with Cases one will be able to insert other custom/standard object records via a custom email service.

**On Demand Email to Case**

This is a Salesforce OOTB functionality that is used for creating ONLY Case records without ANY coding involved. On Demand Email to Case is not related to or does not need a Email Service for its functionality.

Am I right ?.

From the definition, it looks like Email Services is much more versatile as we can build complex custom logic and we can process any type of object records.

Then why there is a need for On Demand Email to Case  ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Email to Case** is a very specific application that allows your customers to send emails that either

a) Open a new Case
b) carry on a threaded conversation about a previously-opened Case via email

These Cases can have attachments. Inbound email to case email is automatically inserted into a special Sobject called EmailMessage, used in earlier version only for email to case. This appears as a related list under Case.

You can then wire up workflows on EmailMessage to enhance your case processing.

A 100% point and click solution

**InboundEmailServices** is a framework for building any application that can accept emails routed to the email services address. I would not use it for support case business processes as you would have to replicate too much functionality.

Apex and testmethods required